# Access all the elements of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to access a value of an object inside an array list. I'm doing array[0].date to access the date value of first index. But what If I want to log for all the indexes instead of just the first element. Do I have to use a for loop or is there any other way for that?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can use any iteration method for this.

You can do either a standart [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) console.log(array[i].date);
```

or [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array)'s built-in method [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

```
array.forEach(item => console.log(item.date));
```

or even ES6 [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax

```
for (const item of array) console.log(item.date);
```

Comment: What if it's an object inside multiple arrays in that case how can I use the forEach?
I mean array[{array[{date:date}]}.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   console.log(array[i].date);
}
```

If you want to store the dates on another array and display them, you may do:

```
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   console.log(array[i].date);
   newArray.push(array[i].date);
}

console.log(newArray.toString());
```